# How can I capture all points belonging to the same series with the same xAxis value without a loop?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I don't know if this is a bug with Highcharts, but I'm plotting two values within the same series on the same xAxis on a chart and I'd like to be able to capture all points within the same xAxis in a tooltip. Unfortunately Highcharts is under the impression that only one of the points exists:

[image: Example]

In fact, if you hover over the far left point and move your cursor over the central point with the value `1`, the point for value `2` will be highlighted and that is the point Highcharts believes I'm hovering over.

I could use a loop to determine which points also exist, but where I'm using a shared tooltip and my production chart can have hundreds of points plotted across a lot of different series, I think this would be a very resource-intensive approach.

[Here is a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h11xfs5L/1/) which generates the above chart using the below series data:

```
series: [{
    data: [
        { x: 0, y: 1 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 2 }
    ]
}]
```

I've also defined the following `tooltip` properties:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
        return "Points: " + this.points.length + "<br>Value: " + this.y;
    }
}
```

If we debug `this.points` when hovering over the central line, we'll see that all it contains is:

```
[Object] 0: Object
    key: 1,
    percentage: undefined,
    point: Ga,
    series: c,
    total: undefined,
    x: 1,
    y: 2
```

There's no mention of the `{ x: 1, y: 1 }` point at all.

How can I also capture and display this data in my tooltip alongside the `{ x: 1, y: 2 }` point without having to loop through every point in every series to find similar points in the tooltip `formatter` function?

---

#### Update

Another good example of the problem surrounding this is when enabling `allowPointSelect`: you simply cannot click the `{ x: 1, y: 1 }` point - when you do, the `{ x: 1, y: 2 }` point is selected instead. [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h11xfs5L/3/).

[image: Example 2]

Comment: So, where `x` is 1, return all the objects from the array (formatted)?

Comment: @Andy which array? The `this.points` array only contains the one point: `{ x: 1, y: 2 }`.

Comment: @Andy I don't want the entire data array. Also see the paragraph above the JSFiddle link. That still doesn't change the fact that the other point doesn't get highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1: Selecting the closest point**

With a line chart, Highcharts calculates the nearest point based purely on horizontal distance the point and your mouse.

This means that once it's built it's point tree, given two points with the same x, it'll always return the first one it hits.

You can override this to use the actual distance to the point like so:

```
series.kdComparer = 'distR';
```

It should then give you the genuine closest point.

**Update: Selecting Other Points**

To get other points with the same x value on the same series, you can take advantage of Highcharts k-d point tree. Searching through this is **much** faster than searching through the series points.

Here's an updated fiddle which does this. Note this still works even if the matching points are not declared in sequence. It also lets you find points that have exactly the same coordinates.

http://jsfiddle.net/h11xfs5L/18/

Comment: Interesting solution, and whilst this does certainly work for the `allowPointSelect` issue I've noted at the end, it still doesn't allow for both points to be pulled into the same shared tooltip - which is ideally the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: Another issue which I didn't mention in the question is if two points have the exact same `x` and `y` values - I'd like to be able to display that there are multiple occurrences, but this would also not allow that to happen unfortunately.